# How to use selected options to display specific pages?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set up a small website with a user form. A user would select options in four fields and would go to a different results page according to his/her selections, based on user input.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
function testSelect (form) {
Item1 = form.location.selectedIndex;
Item2 = form.type.selectedIndex;
Item3 = form.bedrooms.selectedIndex;
Item4 = form.pricerange.selectedIndex;
Result1 = form.location.options[Item1].text;
Result2 = form.type.options[Item2].text;
Result3 = form.bedrooms.options[Item3].text;
Result4 = form.pricerange.options[Item4].text;
var input = Result1 +" "+ Result2 +" "+ Result3 +" "+ Result4;
if (input = "Town A Villa Two bedrooms 120.000 to 180.000 €") {
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
}     
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" action="" method="GET">
<input type="button" namelijktton" value="Search" onClick="testSelect(this.form)">
<select name="location">
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a location</option>
<option>Town A</option>
<option>Town B</option>
</select>
<select name="type">
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a type</option>
<option>Villa</option>
<option>Apartment</option>
</select>
<select name="bedrooms">
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select number of bedrooms</option>
<option>Two bedrooms</option>
<option>Three bedrooms</option>
</select>
<select name="pricerange">
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a price range</option>
<option>120.000 to 180.000 €</option>
<option>180.000 to 250.000 €</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I can get the script to work when conditions "Town A Villa Two bedrooms 120.000 to 180.000 €" are met, it takes me to the Google page, which I use as a test. But I need to load other pages according to different selected options. How should I take it from there, for instance with if elseif statements ?

Comment: Please create a working script. So that others can work around it.

Comment: When using 'var selected_bedrooms = Form.elements["bedrooms"]' you have the DOM object node in hand (forget the variable saving each data from each component). When you need it's data you can access from the same variable like obj.selectedIndex, obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value and obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text. This you make your code more clearly and more dynamic, because with objects you have all of them attributes in hand. Mind about that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. I'm editing my original post with a working script, but need to expand it from there.